# MS Access VBA AppActivate "Send fax" and SendKeys

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013, sendkeys, fax

I am sending a series of Access Report to the multifunction fax/printer.  Each report is customized and need to go to a specific phone number.  I want to automate but it keeps getting stuck at the point where the script should input the number and proceed.

```
DoCmd.PrintOut 'This works fine to print to the Fax
```

---

```
AppActivate "Send fax" 'This works as the window focus changes from MS Access to the Send fax dialog box
```

---

```
SendKeys "%f" & rst![Fax] 'This does not work and when I move the mouse around, I get a pointer when on the Send fax dialog box but a busy spinning circle when I move the mouse away from the dialog box.  It seems the process is hung up at AppActivate and not letting this part work.
```

---

```
SendKeys "%d99" 'This part would thus not work also
```

---

```
SendKeys "{Enter} 'This part would thus not work also
```

Comment: Where is your code? A printscreen of the dialog box, what exactly do you want to enter, how is that data stored. Etc.. Also see [mcve]

Comment: The codes in question starts at line 4 "DoCmd.PrintOut..." I added comments with a single quote right after it.  Basically, on the "Send fax" dialog box, I want to automate Alt-F to go to the fax box and put in the custom fax number as defined by rst![Fax] and then Alt-D to enter dialing prefix of '99' and then hit enter.

Comment: As you've discovered, `SendKeys` is unreliable and should generally be avoided. Fax machines are still around, eh? Does your computer even still have a fax modem? Does it work manually? Don't these people have email? You could brush the dust off these old instructions/code from Microsoft that use the VBA reference library **"Microsoft Fax Service Extended COM Type Library"** for faxing to [one](https://docs.microsoft.com/previous-versions/windows/desktop/fax/-mfax-sending-a-fax) or [several](https://docs.microsoft.com/previous-versions/windows/desktop/fax/-mfax-broadcasting-a-fax) recipients.

Comment: So is a network fax/printer (\\networkpath\faxprintername ) considered a fax server?  Working from home today so unable to test...

Comment: I can't say for sure but believe the Windows service used by that library works with both fax servers and local fax machines. More info in [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7006eb1-a3a3-409c-aedd-855683f3d21b/vba-code-to-send-a-fax) (there's some back & forth so skim to the bottom). While tempted to heckle you for using faxes, I just learned that in many cases [fax usage increased last year](https://enterprise.efax.com/blog/the-top-10-reasons-companies-continue-to-fax-in-2017) although [not here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/906708/?tagName=fax).

Comment: No go... I guess the Lexmark MX520 multifunction is not considered as either a fax modem nor a fax server on my network, so unable to install as part of MS Fax.